# is there any simplest way to calculate a recurring day?

Tags: javascript, recurring

i have a recurring data that received from database in number format.

and i have checkbox which show day with this value:

```
[64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1] // monday to sunday
```

and this is how i redefined them into checklist so that i can show in checkbox.:

```
switch (recurring) {
        case 127:
          this.checkedList = [64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1];
          break;
        case 126:
          this.checkedList = [64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2];
          break;
        case 125:
          this.checkedList = [64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 1];
          break;
        case......
        default:
          this.checkedList = [recurring];
      }
```

but i think that's not a good practice because it'll take long code to execute the result. is there any way i could transform it to be more simple?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to define all the different selection combinations, but I'm not sure why? Why can the user not just select the day(s) they want, and you sum the values?

Comment: because i'm using it as initial value which the user will edit them. it's an update data page @fubar

Comment: Understood. Then @meagar has the answer.

Comment: Your `case` statement would have 5040 (that is, 7!) cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are powers of two, meant to be used in a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

You are meant to tell whether a given date is "checked" using bitwise operator `&`.

```
const SUNDAY   = 64; // 0100 0000
const SATURDAY = 32; // 0010 0000
const FRIDAY   = 16; // 0001 0000
const THURSDAY =  8; // 0000 1000
// etc.

let day = 48; // 0011 0000

day & SUNDAY   // 0 indicating Sunday should not be checked
day & SATURDAY // 32 indicating Saturday should be checked
day & FRIDAY   // 16 indicated Friday should be checked
day & THURSDAY // 0 indicated Thursday should not be checked
```

If you want to turn this into an array of checked values, the simplest option would be to stop using a bitfield an instead store a JSON array of strings.

Assuming that's not possible, your case statement can be replaced with something as simple as...

```
const DAYS = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 ];

const dayBitfield = 41;

DAYS.filter(day => dayBitfield & day) // [1, 8, 32]
```

Comment: thank you very much it's worked perfectly. for in my case because of i want to make it into an array so the second way is much better. the first way can be used if we want to auto checked the checkbox. but in my case, i want to send an array into initial value